# Subpanel Edit View

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I have custom code on my Contacts Edit View via the file custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php. I want the same code to work for the Contact subpanel in other modules. How should I do this?

Below is the code I used:

In custom/modules/Contacts/view/view.customedit.php

```
require_once 'include/MVC/View/views/view.edit.php';

class ContactsViewEnjayedit extends ViewEdit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::ViewEdit();
        $this->useForSubpanel = true;
        $this->useModuleQuickCreateTemplate = true;
    }

    protected function _displayJavascript()
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/Contacts/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/Contacts/js/NjContact.js"></script>';
        parent::_displayJavascript();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me way too long to figure out as well and I am happy to share the quite easy answer with you!

In your custom view.edit.php file add the following line inside the __construct() method:

```
$this->useForSubpanel = true;
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for answering.However I have tried it earlier but the code is not working.Please see the question to have a look at the code I have used.Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I tried in Contacts subpanel in Accounts module but not working.

Comment: Hmmm, can you double check that your class name is ContactsViewEdit instead of ContactsViewEnjayedit as it is above.

Also, the file name should be view.edit.php, not view.customedit.php. Without the file named this way Sugar will not know to load your custom view. It is possible to have custom views, but I don't think that is what you want here.

Comment: Lastly, you either need to call your _displayJavascript method somewhere or change it to be display() instead. I recommend renaming that method to display. This will over ride the existing display method in parent class. Make sure that before you echo out the javascript you make a call to parent::display();

Comment: Ohh Thanks Danny.It worked.However I had a custom controller which called the custom editview view.customedit.php.MAking in this file useForSubpanel = true didnt worked.However I changed it to view.edit.php and also the classname then it worked.But can you please let me know how can we do the same thing using custom controller.

Comment: Also can you suggest how to make it work for quick create. I have used $this->useModuleQuickCreateTemplate = true; however this is not working.

Comment: So the thing to think about here is that quick create is loosely related to the edit view. For example, when quick create specific code is not in place it will fall back on the edit view code. However, there is no relationship between quick create and a custom view. If you really want to use a custom controller and have that code work in quick create you will need to use both view.customedit.php AND view.edit.php. Your custom view will use the view.customedit.php file and quick create will use the view.edit.php. What is the requirement for using a custom controller?